# Using "Tab" key to move from NSTextField to NSMatrix

Tags: cocoa, user-interface, nsmatrix

I have a Cocoa Form (xib) which contains some `NSTextField`s and an `NSMatrix` of `NSButtonCell`s. I can use the "Tab" key to tab though the `NSTextField`s, but the `NSMatrix` gets skipped over.

I want to be able to tab into the `NSMatrix`, and tab from one button to the next within the matrix.

I have put in the following line of code, but it is having no effect:

```
[mtxMyMatrix setTabKeyTraversesCells:YES];
```

Can anybody help with this problem or point me to an example? I have searched for hours with no success.

Comment: Have you tried setting "Next Key View" for one of the text fields to be the matrix itself?

Comment: Thanks - yes I have. The focus jumps over the matrix to the text field after it, ignoring the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and the solution I found was fiddling with the "first responder" setting. Specifically, making sure that the entire form didn't refuse, and each individual field likewise accepted first responder status. Again, the whole form, and each field as well. I too searched for a while... :( I'm also noob.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough reputation.